# change html form values with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the values of a form with radio inputs in javascript

if i have:

```
<form id="the_form">
    <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value1" checked>
    <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value2">
</form>

<script>
    let the_form = document.getElementById('the_form');
    let newValue = 'value2';
    //what do i do here to make value2 checked using the_form and newValue
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Radio button values don't really change. When you click a radio button, you generally cause something else to happen.

Comment: I am trying to set up a form that multiple webpages will have access to, when one person clicks a radio on one page, the form will be sent to a server which will send back an object with all the values i want on the form, i have that much done i just dont know what to do with the newly acquired object to reset the form short of rebuilding the whole form

Comment: *"when one person clicks a radio on one page, the form will be sent to a server"* That's the job of a `<input type=submit>`, not a radio button. I think you have a fundamental design flaw here.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you are using radio buttons incorrectly. The `value` of the button is typically static. You can certainly set up an event handler to do something when it is clicked, but having a button change its own value is not how to use them.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point to radio buttons, that they change values when picked?? sorry I am new to this but I don't understand whats wrong with this approach

Comment: No, the point is to have a set of radio buttons that all share the same `name` (to group them), each having their own unique static `value`. When the form is submitted, the selected radio button sends the value it was created with as part of the form's data payload. The value isn't meant to change when the button is clicked.

Comment: There is no button on my form, just radio check boxes, the idea is that every time someone in a lobby for a game makes a change to the form, it will update for everyone in the game lobby. The form is never really submitted, the values in the game's object get changed when handling the data retrieved from the player changing something in the form so it never needs to be submitted as the game object is constantly being updated. It is working now, but I am curious of a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var newValue = 'value2';
document.getElementById(newValue).checked=true;
```

```html
<form id="the_form">
    <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value1" id="value1" checked>
    <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value2" id="value2">
</form>
```

Comment: this makes sense, so the other value will be checked off when this is done right?

Comment: yes, since its a radio button group when one box is checked any other will be automatically unchecked. And do accept the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Get the element using [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and finally update its [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) property.

```html
<form id="the_form">
  <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value1" checked>
  <input type="radio" title="this_radio" name="this_radio" value="value2">
</form>

<script>
  let the_form = document.getElementById('the_form');
  let newValue = 'value2';

  document.querySelector('[value="' + newValue + '"]').checked = true;
</script>
```

Comment: why using querySelector when you can just simply use
document.getElementById("value1").checked=true;

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif : there is no attribute for the element